# Rendering a 'multiple' page App from one React file

Tags: reactjs

Hello fellow SO users !

I have a question about react and trying to display a multiple page application all in one html document but not loading everything at the beginning of course but whenever each one page is accessed.

So here's an example:

```
return( 
<div>{
 if something<*MainPage/>
 else<*SecondPage/>}
</div> );
```

Is something like this possible ?

Thank you in advance !

Have a great day !

Comment: I will suggest you to read through the [React beginner's guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) first before asking in SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, Consider the example code below

```js
class User extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.isGuest) {
      return <h1>You are guest</h1>
    }else {
      return <h1>You are logged in</h1>
    } 
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<User isGuest={false} />,document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

As you can see the line: this.props.isGuest
I have passed it false, So you are able to see:
You are logged in